# Cannot get mySql started on MAMP 3.5.2

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

Due to untold issues with my workflow using MAMP 4, I decided to revert back to MAMP Pro 3.5.2. However I cannot get the mySQL to start. I feel like I've tried everything:

Reinstall
kill processes
Change permission on MAMP folder to 777 including sub folders.
run MAMP instead
Nothing works (mySql won't even start in MAMP (non-pro)

In the GUI I get: The MySQL configuration file my.cnf couldn't be written.

Error logs say:

161208 21:18:38 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended 161208 21:19:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql 161208 21:19:13 [Warning] Can't create test file /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/Petes-MBP.lower-test 161208 21:19:13 [Warning] Can't create test file /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/Petes-MBP.lower-test /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' (Errcode: 2) 161208 21:19:13 [ERROR] Aborting

Please help. thanks

Comment: Have you checked if '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' actually exists? Your error message says it doesn't. The easiest option will probably be: Rename your MAMP-folder (after killing the processes), reboot your machine, reinstall, copy your data (hopefully from a backup). Anything else is hard to diagnose from the other side of the world, although you are probably just mixing old and new config files somewhere and could modify them.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the file manually using `touch`, e.g.

```
touch /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/Petes-MBP.lower-test
```

I had the same error but with a different file, and I resolved creating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For my I needed to create a missing dir.

```
mkdir -p /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
```